# On clicking dropdown link, show selected text in button

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm using [Foundation: Dropdown buttons](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown_buttons.html) and want to slightly tweak how it works.

In my example below, when a link in the dropdown is clicked, would it be possible to show the text of that link in the button?

E.g After clicking "yet another", the button text will read "Order list by: yet another".

```
<button href="#" data-dropdown="drop1" aria-controls="drop1" aria-expanded="false" class="button dropdown">Order list by: </button><br>
<ul id="drop1" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown" aria-hidden="true">
    <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say drop down, but are showing an unordered list. Either way, you can use jquery to accomplish this. Also, add a span inside your button to append the text inside.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cshanno/rvkhwpn5/1/

JS

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
    $('button span').text($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the text "Order list by:" then change the bit after the colon?

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Will accept as soon as it'll let me.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the original text, you need to create an inline span element inside your button

```
<button href="#" data-dropdown="drop1" aria-controls="drop1" aria-expanded="false" class="button dropdown">Order list by: <span id="orderBy"></div></button><br>

$("li a").on("click", function() {
    $("button #orderBy").text($(this).text());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jmyem32r/3/

Comment: @richadhamilton Is there a way to keep the text "Order list by:" then change the bit after the colon?

Comment: @Ricchard it ll append previously selected text as well

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I'll fix that